# Retrieving @NamedQuery from interface of JPA Entity

Tags: java, jpa-2.1

I have a JPA 2.1 project, database has 2 tables. I have created an interface "UsedClasses.java" and have both Entities implement the interface., i.e.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "runRanges")
@NamedQuery(name = "RunRange.findAll", query = "SELECT r FROM RunRange r")
public class RunRange extends AbstractTimestampEntity implements UsedClasses, Serializable ....
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User extends AbstractTimestampEntity implements UsedClasses, Serializable ...
```

I am curious to know if I can use the interface to grab the NamedQuery for either of the Entities.
What I am trying to accomplish if getting the results list according to the class.

```
    public List<UsedClasses> getAllItems() {
    open();
    Query query = EntityManagerHandler.INSTANCE.getEntityManager().createQuery(UsedClasses.class.getResource(NamedQueries));

    List<UsedClasses> aList = query.getResultList();
    return aList;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but you should use reflection to retrieve the `NamedQuery` annotation and you would need to have the `UsedClasses` instance and not the interface like in your example :

```
Query query = EntityManagerHandler.INSTANCE.getEntityManager().createQuery(UsedClasses.class.getResource(NamedQueries));
```

Besides, if you add multiple annotations, it will not work any longer.

I think that a more simple and clean solution would be to add a method in your interface to get the namedQuery String name.

For example

```
public interface UsedClasses(){
     String getNamedQueryForGetAll();     
}
```

And you could implement it in this way :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements UsedClasses(){
     public String getNamedQueryForGetAll(){            
         return "User.findAll";
     }
}
```

Then you can use it in this way :

```
Query query = EntityManagerHandler.INSTANCE.getEntityManager().createQuery(usedClassInstance.getNamedQueryForGetAll());
```

Now, I find that it creates a little of duplication and it is not straight readable.
`NamedQuery` brings a extremely tiny performance improvement.
I am not sure that the complexity/indirection level introduced in the code to gain so few in terms of execution time makes you winning.

Comment: To your first suggestion:
Query query = EntityManagerHandler.INSTANCE.getEntityManager().createQuery(UsedClasses.class.getResource(NamedQueries));
This does not work. The error message states
NamedQueries cannot be resolved to a variable.

To your second suggestion:
I do not understand how to use it because I do not instantiate UsedClasses in the class the creates the query. How do I invoke the method getNamedQueryForGetAll()?

Comment: Ok, you answered the question as I was editing. Sorry. But now I do not see how the instance knows which class it interfaced too.